# Conditional joint probability into an expectation of a product of conditional probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have a question regarding how to turn a joint conditional probability into an expectation of a product.

Consider a finite i.i.d. sequence $\mathbf{Z} = (Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_m)$ with $P(Z_j = 1) = P(Z_j = -1) = 0.5$. Define two binary random variables $X$ and $Y$ via
\begin{align*}
    P(X = 1 \mid Z_1 = z_1, Z_2 = z_2, \ldots, Z_m = z_m) 
    &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j \geq 1} z_j 2^{-j} \\ 
    P(Y = 1 \mid Z_1 = z_1, Z_2 = z_2, \ldots, Z_m = z_m) 
    &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j \geq 1}(-1)^{j} z_j 2^{-j}
\end{align*}
and $X \perp\!\!\!\perp Y \mid \mathbf{Z}$.

If one only conditions on the first $d < m$ variables, for $d$ even, the conditional probabilities become
\begin{align}
    P(X = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
    &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j = 1}^{d} z_j 2^{-j} + \frac{1}{2}Z_k 2^{-k} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j > k} Z_j 2^{-j} \\ 
    \nonumber 
    P(Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
    &= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j = 1}^{d} (-1)^{j} z_j 2^{-j} - \frac{1}{2}Z_k 2^{-k} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j > k}(-1)^{j} Z_j 2^{-j}, 
\end{align}
where the notation $\mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}$ means $(Z_1 = z_1, Z_2 = z_2, \ldots, Z_d = z_d)$ and $k = d + 1$.

Now, my question is how to write the joint probability $P(X = 1, Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) $ into an expectation of the two conditional probabilities above i.e.
\begin{align}
    P(X = 1, Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
    = 
    \mathbb{E}
    \left[
        P(X = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
        P(Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
    \right]. 
\end{align}
My thought was to first note that while $X$ and $Y$ are binary it holds that $P(X = 1, Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) = \mathbb{E}[XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}]$. This conditional expectation is essentially a random variable where the randomness come from the random variables that we haven't conditioned on i.e. $Z_{d + 1}, \ldots , Z_m$. Furthermore, using the law of iterated expectations it holds that
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}[XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}]
    = 
    \mathbb{E}\left\{
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \mathbb{E}(XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]})
            \mid \mathbf{Z}
        \right]
    \right\}.
\end{align}
Is is possible to use the conditional independence $X \perp\!\!\!\perp Y \mid \mathbf{Z}$ in the inner expectation above such that it factorizes into the product of the conditional expectations as
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}\left\{
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \mathbb{E}(XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]})
            \mid \mathbf{Z}
        \right]
    \right\} 
    &=
    \mathbb{E}\left\{
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]})
            \mathbb{E}(Y\mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]})
            \mid \mathbf{Z}
        \right]
    \right\} \\ 
    &=  
    \mathbb{E}\left\{
        \mathbb{E}\left[
                P(X = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
                P(Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
            \mid \mathbf{Z}
        \right]
    \right\} \\ 
    &= 
    \mathbb{E}\left\{
        P(X = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
        P(Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}) 
    \right\}
\end{align*}
or is this not allowed because we have conditioned on $(\mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]})$ and therefore the conditional independence does not hold?

Comment: There seems to be an extra expectation on the rhs, which breaks the equality: 
$\mathbb{E}[XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}]  = 
    \mathbb{E}\left\{
        \mathbb{E}\left[
            \mathbb{E}(XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]})
            \mid \mathbf{Z}
        \right]
    \right\}$

Comment: @paperskilltrees 
Ah yes. Maybe I should write $\mathbb{E}(XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]}) = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}(XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]} = \mathbf{z}_{[1, d]}, \mathbf{Z}_{[d+1, m]})\right]$ instead and use the same arguments? But does the conditional independence then hold in the inner expectation again such that it factorizes into a product?

Comment: The [LIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) reads $E[E[U|V]]=E[U]$, which becomes $E[g(\dots)]\equiv E[E[XY|Z_{[1,d]}]]=E[XY]$. You can also use the property known as [stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) to obtain $E[XY|Z_{[1,d]}]=E[E[XY|Z_{[1,d]}]|Z]$. What you wrote in the comment is still wrong:  as you correctly mentioned, on the lhs _"randomness come from the random variables that we haven't conditioned"_, but on the rhs there is "no randomness". The two can't be equal in general.

Comment: Once you take unconditioned expectation $E[\dots ]$, all "randomness" disappears.

Comment: I see, thanks! But would I then be able to use the stability property to obtain 
$\mathbb{E}(XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]}) = \mathbb{E}\left\{
    \mathbb{E}(XY \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]}) \mid \mathbf{Z}
\right\}
= 
\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]})\mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathbf{Z}_{[1, d]}) \mid \mathbf{Z}\right\}
$
?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your whole question (you might want to edit it anyway, as it is currently asking if $E[\dots | Z_{[1,d]}] = E[\dots]$). As for the question in your last comment, the second equality is equivalent to random variables $X_d := E[X|Z_{[1,d]}]$ and $Y_d := E[Y|Z_{[1,d]}]$ being uncorrelated, which does not have to hold for arbitrary $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: Correction to this sentence, which I misread. _"This conditional expectation is essentially a random variable where the randomness come from the random variables that we haven't conditioned on"_ - the contrary is true: conditional expectation is a random variable where the randomness comes from the random variable the we _have_ conditioned on. The randomness from the variables that we haven't conditioned on is eliminated. For example, when we don't condition on anything, $E[\dots]$, all randomness is eliminated.